# Question about partial fractions and integration.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**My question**

*Find the finite region bounded by the curve with equation $y = \frac{2}{(x - 1)(x - 3)}$ and the lines $x = 4$ and $y = \frac{1}{4}$.*

**How do I solve this?** Which area is being meant here?

The graph:

[image: The graph:]
.

I am probably going in the wrong direction with this, since **the curve is undefined at $x = 1$ and $x = 3$** But I tried splitting the equation into partial fractions as such:

$$
\int\frac{1}{x - 3}dx - \int\frac{1}{x - 1}dx = \ln|x-3|
 - \ln|x -1| + c
$$

And then calculate the area from $x = 0$ to $x = 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...when $y=\frac 14$, $x=5$, so you need to evaluate the integral between the limits of $x=4$ and $x=5$, then subtract the area of the rectangle of height $\frac 14$ and width $1$ to get the required area